# Relationship between not found, dif, and \+

Tags: prolog

Conceptually what's the relationship between `false`, `dif`, and `\+`.

Given this program:

```
likes(john, mary).
```

What is being asked exactly when executing the query:

```
\+ like(john, A).
```

And why is the answer not:

```
dif(A, mary).
```

The more I think about it, the more I'm convinced that I don't understand the meaning of negation in Prolog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*`\+ like(john, A)`*

(This is an malformed query if variable `A` behind the `\+` is unbound at call time: [floundering](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/blob/master/other_notes/about_negation/floundering.md))

`\+` is an operator that is defined *procedurally*:

- prove the query on the right of `\+`
- If it succeeds then fail.

In other words, "if you can't find evidence for it, assume it's false" aka. "default negation". An attitude taken in relational databases for one. It is basically a replacement for the problem that Prolog doesn't have strongly negated statements, but turns out to be a welcome extension that the philosophers of logic hadn't even come up with earlier.

*`dif(A, mary).`*

Is much simpler: "Make sure that `A` and `mary` do not unify on this branch of the computation". A *constraint* is set up that will cause unification of `mary` and `A` to fail, either immediately if `A` is already bound to `mary` or later. Compare with `A \= mary` which states that `A` and `mary` do not unification *at the time this statement is encountered*, and so is not really a "logic statement" at all.

I collected some notes on [negation as failure](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/tree/master/other_notes/about_negation) and [dif/2](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/tree/master/swipl_notes/about_dif) which need to be reworked. Still useful.

Comment: Reading through your notes (which are great), I assume the primary purpose of predicates like `member_t(E, List, T)` is to temporarily escape into the domain of deterministic + binary logic.

Comment: @vasily Hold on, this is in which page? I can't remember, it's been some time...

Comment: `memberd` is on your "dif/2" page, `memberd_t` is from this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.01590.pdf

Comment: _temporarily escape into the domain of deterministic + binary logic._ I wouldn't put it like that. It's just that if one queries `member(X,List)` and this succeeds (either by "confirming" if all arguments are ground, or by binding an unbound argument in `List`, one may not want to see more successes: one is already informed that `List` indeed contains `X` or at least does not forbid that `X` be a member of it. The standard `member/2` will yield additional successes. Logicwise, it could be regarded as striking out a few of identical OR-ed literals.

Comment: Is it fair to say that `if_` and `dif` let us define monotone predicates without closed world assumption?

Comment: As far as I know, that is the intent, yes. It's basically a restricted negation that behaves classically.